# Remove unused apps from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I can't remove "Facebook Messenger for iPhone", "Facebook for Windows Phone", "Developer Insights", "Letterboxd" and "RunKeeper". (In third image same text appears on Logged in Anonymously)

**My apps**

[image: My apps]

**Activity**

[image: Activity Log]

**Apps settings**

[image: Apps Settings]

I've disconnected Letterboxd connection from `letterboxd.com`, removed RunKeeper account from `runkeeper.com`. Still there.

What should I do?